# JMeter script saving log's at same time

Tags: database, jmeter

My JMeter script is saving the logs like it had acted at same time, always.
See the image below:

[image]

For example, if I run it 1 million times, it will save 1 million records at same hour (this case, at 2024-02-07 20:09:03:673). But I run the same, manually (using the browser), it will save the current date time (like the first record).
I tried to execute 1 user at once, but the result was the same.

**Is there something I need to do in JMeter config to clear any Login register or something like that?**

Cache and Cookies are cleared every time. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like missing or improperly implemented [request parameterization](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start).

For example if you recorded your test scenario using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) it might be the case you simply recorded the timestamp of the request and next time you run your test the "boards" will be created with the start date of 7th of Feb 2024 at 20:09.

Take another look at the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler which created the "board" and search for anything looking like a timestamp. It might be a number like [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), for example `1707369686062`

If this is the case - replace recorded hard-coded value with [__time() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) (make sure to provide correct pattern) and your "boards" will be created with the current time instead of hard-coded time.

If you want random timestamps and/or timestamps in the past/future instead of current - take a look at [__timeShift() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-timeshift-function)